# Why are all my photos overexposed?

Tags: exposure, mirrorless

I've started to get this problem recently. I have a mirrorless Samsung NX1000. The problem is that my photos are overexposed, especially photos taken outside. I have to use an exposure compensation of -3 just to get decent usable photos. I'm getting overexposed photos in Aperture priority and Shutter priority even after setting the aperture to 20 and the shutter speed to 1/4000s. The overexposure is unusable. Here's an example:

[image: Example picture]

EXIF
Focal Length : 24mm
F-Number : f22
Exposure time : 1/60
ISO : 200
Shutter Priority
Exposure Compensation : 0

I'm not sure how this problem started. But about a year ago, my lens was broken due to a bumpy ride. Eventually, I was able to get it fixed in a camera shop. After the fix everything was working OK until now.

Comment: Have you checked that your ISO isn't very high?

Comment: Maybe you could describe the events before this problem began?

Comment: Last year I had my lens broken due to bumpy ride. Repair shop guy was able to fix it and everything was working fine until now. also. Added image with EXIF

Comment: Do you get correct exposure if you shoot with the lens wide open? If so, that would strongly imply the aperture mechanism is broken.I

Comment: 1/60 speed can be a very long time with f22 and ISO 200 if you are in direct sunlight

Comment: Can you adjust your title to describe your particular situation more specifically? As it is, the question invites people who have overexposed images for all number of reasons.

Comment: you can check the aperture function with the DOF preview button. http://www.manualslib.com/manual/416447/Samsung-Nx1000.html?page=23

Answer (score 3):

I notice an unsharp region in the lower right of the frame. At f/22, i wouldn't expect that, but the image doesn't lend itself very well to judge DoF.

I assume your lens doesn't adjust aperture correctly as commanded by the camera. Try to set it to its widest value in aperture priority and shoot with the calculated exposure time. If this comes out ok, the lens is simply defect.

Answer (score 2):

in shutter/aperture priority modes, you are choosing shutter speed OR aperture and the camera is choosing the other 2 inputs that determine exposure; ISO and aperture/shutter speed. The camera makes it's decision on the amount light being detected at the sensor, but the amount of light used in the "decision" is heavily affected by the metering mode which is the choice of the USER. For example in your picture, if you are using spot metering and the spot is aligned with a dark area in the frame, the camera will use an ISO/speed/aperture to properly expose only the spot. If the rest of the frame is brighter than the area behind the spot, it will be overexposed.

Check which metering mode you are using, and try the other modes to see how they affect overall exposure.

Also check the exposure meter in the viewfinder just before you press the shutter release; if the indicator is in the middle of the range, it means the camera is set to take a properly exposed picture *based on the metering mode you have chosen*. If your picture is overexposed, then it indicates something is wrong with your camera, or you are using the wrong metering mode.

Sometimes the scene is just too bright to take a correct exposure. Try the lowest ISO, smallest aperture and fastest shutter speed in manual mode. If still too bright use a neutral density filter on the front of the lens.

Comment: Even if the "wrong" metering mode was in use, I'd expect some part of the image to be at least vaguely correctly exposed, but here the whole image is *massively* overexposed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is manual. Camera technology has gotten better in making good for calculated guesses when in auto modes, but it's still a guess. When in manual mode, you'll learn how to use the camera better and prevent this from happening. The most likely cause is that ISO is too high, or the shutter speed too low. On my Canon 600D, I have to put the aperture up to 5.6 and shutter speed to ridiculously high on a bright day. Also, on Canon's, there is the metering bar at the bottom of the display and through the view finder. There is a moving arrow which shows the exposure of the current image. You want to get that pointer at 0.

Comment: Assuming that the meter is broken in some way, which seems likely, the pointer at the bottom will _also_ show an incorrect value.

Answer (score -5):

This may be a common problem with that camera model when encountering heat and humidity in some locales. You may have to send it in to get the shutter replaced. Once replaced you will notice the images improve but also the sound of the shutter is different.